# App Store Connect Operation Error: Invalid provisioning profile... Please use provisioning profile associated with team ID "XX..XX"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, app-store

I developed an app for a friend of mine. We published it to the App store from his laptop and his account. We also published the first update through his account as well.

Currently, we need to push a third update, but I am physically away from him and I have to do it from my account and laptop. He made me an **"admin"** on his developer account team.
[image]

Using my developer account, I created new certificates and new provisioning profiles (as his certificates and provisioning profiles expired). The app deploys normally when I test it on my iPhone device.

When I try to upload the app to the App Store, I receive the following error:

[image]

**My team ID** is (**59..DU**). My friend's **team ID** where we published the app and pushed the first update is (**JB..22**) (The one the error is showing).

I've been trying for almost two days. I tried everything I could, my problem is mainly the team associated with the provisioning profile. The code signing works fine (no errors) whether it's manual or automatic. I also signed out then signed in for my developer account on xcode. I also verified the bundle ID. Nothing seemed to work.

How can I upload the app using my friend's team ID (**JB..22**) from my developer account? Keeping in mind that I cannot use his credentials and I'm physically away from him to do this from his laptop.

I would appreciate any help in this matter.

Comment: You need to be logged into the Apple ID for the account that is linked to the team you're publishing to (check Preferences > Accounts in Xcode), and you also need the private key for the distribution certificate to be able to distribute the app. Your friend can export his private key and send it to you. Make sure your project settings also point to the correct Team in the "Signing" section under "General". Note Apple Developer is separate from [App Store Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com) as well. And note you need to build again if you change the provisioning profiles.

Comment: Go to Keychain Access in 1st laptop and create a p12 or .pem file and install(Double click on files) it in the 2nd laptop. And then try it will work.

Answer (score 0):

- Please verify if it's `App Store Distribution` profile or not.
- If `Yes`, then try to login to Xcode with your `Apple Id` which has access to `iTunes Connect` or `App Store Connect`.
- While validating the archive file please choose the same `App Store Distribution` profile.